# Python - call multiple methods in a single call

Tags: python

how can i call multiple methods of an object at the same time in python. in php I can do this:

```
class Client{
    public ac1(){ ... }

    public ac2(){ ... }
}

$client = new client();
$client->ac1()->ac2(); <-- I want to do it here
```

how would you do it in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you gave of PHP code does *not* run the methods at the same time - it just combines the 2 calls in a single line of code. This pattern is called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

You can do the same in Python as long as a method you're calling returns the instance of the object it was called on.

I.e.:

```
class Client:
    def ac1(self):
        ...
        return self

    def ac2(self):
        ...
        return self


c = Client()
c.ac1().ac2()
```

Note that `ac1()` gets executed first, returns the (possibly modified in-place) instance of the object and then `ac2()` gets executed on that returned instance.

Some major libraries that are popular in Python are moving towards this type of interface, a good example is `pandas`. It has many methods that allow in-place operations, but the package is moving towards deprecating those in favour of chainable operations, returning a modified copy of the original.

Comment: Wasn't returning the self. thank you so much. It worked out!

Comment: You're welcome. If the response answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark next to it so that your question no longer appears as unanswered. If you require further help, add a comment detailing it, or update your question.